# Is there a way to "transform" a CSV table into a simple nested if... else block in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm fairly new to python and I'm looking forward to achieve the following:

I have a table with several conditions as in the image below (maximum 5 conditions) along with various attributes. Each condition comes from a specific set of values, for example Condition 1 has 2 possible values, Condition 2 has 4 possible values, Condition 3 has 2 possible values etc..

[image: ![enter image description here]

What I would like to do: From the example table above, I would like to generate a simple python code so that when I execute my function and import a CSV file containing the table above, I should get the following output saved as a *.py file:

```
def myFunction(Attribute, Condition):
  if Attribute1 & Condition1:
    myValue = val_11
  if Attribute1 & Condition2:
    myValue = val_12
  ...
  ...
  if Attribute5 & Condition4:
    myValue = val_54
```

NOTE: Each CSV file will contain only one sheet and the titles for the columns do not change.

**UPDATE, NOTE#2**: Both "Attribute" and "Condition" are string values, so simple string comparisons would suffice.

Is there a simple way to do this? I dove into NLP and realized that it is not possible (at least from what I found in the literature). I'm open to all forms of suggestions/answers.

Comment: not an answer to your question; tables in python you really want to work with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)

Comment: How are the conditions written?

Comment: @LinFelix all conditions are strings, so a simple string compare is sufficient, the final values (column: myVal) are also strings so a simple assignment would be sufficient there

Comment: Then every condition is true because `Bool("text")` yields `True`. Do you want to understand the conditions? Do you not need to parse them?

Comment: @LinFelix you are correct, I should better update my data. I have modified it the CSV files to be much easier now, please check the updated image and info the question

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use "If"s and "else"s, since, if I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to read the conditions, attributes and values from a CSV file. Using "If"s and "else"s, you would only be able to check a fixed range of conditions and attributes defined in your code. What I would do, is to write a parser (piece of code, which reads the contents of your CSV file and saves it in another, more usable form).

In this case, the parser is the `parseCSVFile()` function. Instead of the ifs and elses comparing attributes and conditions, you now use the attributes and conditions to access a specific element in a dictionary (similar to an array or list, but you can now use for example string *keys* instead of the numerical *indexes*). I used a dictionary containing a dictionary at each position to split the CSV contents into their rows and columns. Since I used dictionaries, you can now use the strings of the Attributes and Conditions to access your values instead of doing lots of comparisons.

```
#Output Dictionary
ParsedDict = dict()

#This is either ';' or ',' depending on your operating system or you can open a CSV file with notepad for example to check which character is used
CSVSeparator = ';'

def parseCSVFile(filePath):
    global ParsedDict
    f = open(filePath)
    fileLines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    #Extract the conditions
    ConditionsArray = (fileLines[0].split(CSVSeparator))[1:]

    for x in range(len(fileLines)-1):
        #Remove unwanted characters such as newline characters
        line = fileLines[1 + x].strip()
        #Split by the CSV separation character
        LineContents = line.split(CSVSeparator)
        ConditionsDict = dict()
        for y in range(len(ConditionsArray)):
            ConditionsDict.update({ConditionsArray[y]: LineContents[1 + y]})
        ParsedDict.update({LineContents[0]: ConditionsDict})

def myFunction(Attribute, Condition):
    myValue = ParsedDict[Attribute][Condition]
```

The "[1:]" is to ignore the contents in the first column (empty field at the top left and the "Attribute x" fields) when reading either the conditions or the values

Use the `parseCSVFile()` function to extract the information from the csv file

and the `myFunction()` to get the value you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have two concerns: firstly, I'm looking to generate a function using Python that will extract `myValue' when executed. I will do my research on it even further.

Also, in your code, no matter which attribute and condition is chosen, the result only shows the conditions from the last column, which does not correspond to the attribute

Comment: you only need to update the inner dict as well, then you code will work

Comment: I updated the code! It works for me now. I just had to update the dictionary on the inside separately, I didn't notice that it's overwriting the old conditions when updating both at the same time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).